# How to split the not regularly whitespace fields using awk or like others?

Tags: linux, string

I want to split the data as below:

```
$1       $2           $3               $4  $5  $6 $7       $8   .........
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root     tty5                          Wed Dec 18 13:42:28 2019   still logged in             
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~
                      ^                ^
root     tty5                          Wed Dec 18 11:23:20 2019 - Wed Dec 18 11:24:47 2019  (00:01)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Sep  3 10:11:31 2019 - Tue Sep  3 10:21:18 2019  (00:09)    
john     pts/3        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 14:42:29 2019 - Mon Sep  2 14:57:33 2019  (00:15)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 14:40:03 2019 - Mon Sep  2 14:45:27 2019  (00:05)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 13:52:09 2019 - Mon Sep  2 14:34:12 2019  (00:42)    
john     pts/3        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 13:14:39 2019 - Mon Sep  2 14:03:24 2019  (00:48)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 13:08:11 2019 - Mon Sep  2 13:23:16 2019  (00:15)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 10:22:27 2019 - Mon Sep  2 11:10:48 2019  (00:48)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Fri Aug 30 17:25:19 2019 - Fri Aug 30 17:33:34 2019  (00:08)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Wed Aug 28 10:43:56 2019 - Wed Aug 28 10:52:48 2019  (00:08)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Aug 27 16:59:30 2019 - Tue Aug 27 17:52:50 2019  (00:53)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Aug  6 11:06:46 2019 - Tue Aug  6 11:12:05 2019  (00:05)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Aug  6 10:48:39 2019 - Tue Aug  6 11:01:46 2019  (00:13)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Aug  6 10:38:18 2019 - Tue Aug  6 10:43:18 2019  (00:05)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Aug  6 10:28:02 2019 - Tue Aug  6 10:36:04 2019  (00:08)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Fri Aug  2 14:24:00 2019 - Fri Aug  2 14:24:16 2019  (00:00)    
root     tty5                          Fri Aug  2 14:21:30 2019 - Fri Nov 22 11:03:20 2019 (111+20:41) 
root     tty5                          Fri Jul 26 11:02:17 2019 - Fri Jul 26 11:03:58 2019  (00:01)    
john     pts/3        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Thu Jul 25 16:24:44 2019 - Thu Jul 25 16:33:36 2019  (00:08)    
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Thu Jul 25 16:08:41 2019 - Thu Jul 25 16:33:53 2019  (00:25)
```

but, if $3 is empty, I could not get correctly value of $3 and next fields. for example:

```
$ last -F | grep -E 'tty|pty|pts' | awk '{print $3}'
Wed                 <- not correct
Wed                 <- not correct
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
Fri                 <- not correct
Fri                 <- not correct
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

How can I parse it correctly using awk or similar command line tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case let's use this filter:

```
awk '{if ($4 !~ /^(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)$/) $3="- "$3; print}'
```

If everything is fine, `$4` is `Mon` or `Tue` or `Wed` or… Empty `$3` makes `$4` contain `Jan` or `Feb` or `Mar` or…

We detect this. In case `$4` is not what we expect, we inject an extra field to `$3` to shift fields. The altered output is no longer columnized, it looks like this (fragment):

```
root tty5 - Wed Dec 18 13:42:28 2019 still logged in
root tty5 - Wed Dec 18 11:23:20 2019 - Wed Dec 18 11:24:47 2019 (00:01)
john     pts/2        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Tue Sep  3 10:11:31 2019 - Tue Sep  3 10:21:18 2019  (00:09)
john     pts/3        xx.xxx.xx.xxx    Mon Sep  2 14:42:29 2019 - Mon Sep  2 14:57:33 2019  (00:15)
```

To see that it works we can pipe the result to `column -t`:

```
root  tty5   -              Wed  Dec  18  13:42:28  2019  still  logged  in
root  tty5   -              Wed  Dec  18  11:23:20  2019  -      Wed     Dec  18  11:24:47  2019  (00:01)
john  pts/2  xx.xxx.xx.xxx  Tue  Sep  3   10:11:31  2019  -      Tue     Sep  3   10:21:18  2019  (00:09)
john  pts/3  xx.xxx.xx.xxx  Mon  Sep  2   14:42:29  2019  -      Mon     Sep  2   14:57:33  2019  (00:15)
```

But you don't need `column` to reliably parse further.

Notes:

- Your `last` uses English abbreviations; so does mine, in spite of majority of my Kubuntu being localized. I don't know if there is ever a localized `last`, but in case there is, one can probably force it to use English by specifying the `C` locale:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C last -F | …
  ```
- There's a column with possible values `still` and `-`. This way you can easily detect `still logged in`.